# format error,with encountered the symbol?

Tags: javascript

i seriously suck at format.
VJS  VARCHAR2(3000);
im working with this javascript function and i keep getting error
[Error] PLS-00103 (633: 20): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "}" when expecting one of the following:

- & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
  like4

  VJS := VJS||'var G_REL_URL="'||owa_util.get_cgi_env('SCRIPT_NAME')||'" '||CHR(10);
        VJS := VJS||''||CHR(10)||

  ```
        'function makeRequest(){'||CHR(10)||

            ' var v_data_sales ={'||CHR(10)|| 
            ' pvCurrCd:pvCurrCd:'||CURRDEF||'

               ' };'||CHR(10)|| 
        $.ajax({

        url:G_REL_URL+ "/contr_entry_pkg.SELECT_SALES_CENTERS",
        data:v_data_sales,
        async:false,

        success: function(vRetVal){
              var jsonObj =  eval("("+vRetVal+")");
              // $("div").html(data);
              //processCCResponse(v_data_sales,transCount,retVal);

             }

             });
         };   '||CHR(10)|| ;
  ```

  ps= ||CHR(10)|| is a line feed for plsql.

Answer (score 0):

In this block of code:

```
      'function makeRequest(){'||CHR(10)||

      ' var v_data_sales ={'||CHR(10)|| 
      ' pvCurrCd:pvCurrCd:'||CURRDEF||'

         ' };'||CHR(10)||
```

you have an odd number of single quotes...that might have something to do with it.

EDIT: nevermind...the missing one is at end.